# A lot of errors in my application.css file when I added bootstrap to my rails 7 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

So I decided to add bootstrap to my rails app and after 2 hours of installing it finally 'works' and ummm this happens
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwP4C.jpg)

I tried reinstalling it adding any dependancies that were missing i even started from scratch just to try to add bootstrap to see if it was conflicting with anything, nope this always happens and my newb head cannot understand how to approach fixing it.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below and you will get successful.

> 1. `yarn add bootstrap` (if using npm try: `npm install bootstrap`)
> 2. *app/assets/config/manifest.js* -> **remove** `//= link_directory`
> 3. *config/webpacker.yml* -> **change to** `extract_css: true`
> 4. *app/javascript/packs/application.js* -> **add** `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle"`
> 5. **create** an ***application.css*** file in this path -> `app/javascript/src/application.css`
> 6. *app/javascript/packs/application.js* -> **add**
>
> - 6.1 `import "../src/application.css"`
> - 6.2 `import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle"`
>
> 7. *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb* -> **change** `stylesheet_link_tag` to `stylesheet_pack_tag`
> 8. *app/javascript/src/application.css* -> **add** `@import “bootstrap”;`
> 9. *app/assets/stylesheets* -> **Delete this whole folder** you won't need this anymore.

That's it!! Hope you get it! Any further questions, please share.